# How to get developers to remember to merge their bug fixes everywhere?

Tags: svn, branching-and-merging

We use the branch-per-release model of development with Subversion. We tend to have 2 or 3 active branches at a time - trunk (development), and two release (maintenance) branches (i.e. 5.0 and 6.0).

The problem we keep running into is that if we find a bug in 5.0 and fix it in 5.0, not everyone always remembers to merge their fixes into all branches into which the bugfix needs to be merged (6.0 and trunk in this case).

How do you make sure bug fixes are merged into all necessary branches? What is a good way of going about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is probably just communication and education. Have team meetings - make sure that all of your developers are on the same page. We have a similar SVN structure, and whenever I fix a bug, the first thing I ask myself after committing is, "where else does this need to be merged?" - it's just been hammered into my mind through communication and repetition.

Put the list of branches getting merged bugs on a wiki page or other public document so that it's easily findable by all developers.

Comment: Everyone KNOWS the merging needs to be done. And they might not know WHERE it needs to be done, but they can figure it out or ask someone else. These aren't the issues. The issue is that they FORGET to merge it in everywhere. They are interrupted while merging or something like that, and it just doesn't get done, and nobody knows that it never got merged in.

Comment: It sounds like a management/team issue more than a programmatic one, I guess. You could come up with some sort of convoluted system of SVN hooks or CI monitoring that looks for merges with similar comments across various revisions. But that seems way overcomplicated for something that could just be taken care of with training, I guess. People will start remembering to do it if it will affect their performance reviews!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have dedicated testers?  It should be the testers' responsibility to verify that "fixed" really means "fixed in the 5.0 *and* 6.0 development trees".

Answer (score 0):

Continuous integration could help as well, using 'common' tests for development and maintenance trees.